# Open HTML file with text editor

Tags: text-editor, html

Is it possible to open an HTML file with a text editor for example so that I can edit it's source?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. First [find a text editor](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=text+editor) that you like, then launch the editor and open the HTML file.

Many editors will also show up as an option in the launch menu for HTML files if you open them from a file browser, so you may be able to just find your HTML file in your file browser and select your text editor when you open it.

**Edit:** Per your comments, if you're looking for an "Open With" style menu then I can recommend [File Expert](http://www.appbrain.com/app/file-expert/xcxin.filexpert). You can long press on any file and it will give you an "Open With" option which allows you to choose from the list of your installed applications. There might be other file managers that do this, too, but I'm not sure. [Astro](http://www.appbrain.com/app/astro-file-manager/com.metago.astro) has "Open As" which is a bit more limited since it gives you a list of applications based on the file type you choose (text, music, video, image).

Comment: Ha, thanks. I simplified the question a bit without wanting to. What I wanted to know was if I can somehow trigger an "Open With" panel on any kind of file and open with whatever I want. For example if I want to open an image file with a text editor and so on. Similar to `Right-Click > Open With` in Windows.

Comment: @Francisc: Well, that should work in this case (though I don't know about opening an image with a text editor). I know Ted will show up in the menu if you launch an HTML file with your file browser. As long as you don't mark the "Use by default" checkbox you should see the menu every time. There are probably other editors that do that as well. Is that pretty much what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks again. I am looking for a way to open files (of any sort) with whatever application I want to open that file with. In general.

Comment: @Francisc: Ah, I gotcha. I know [File Expert](http://www.appbrain.com/app/file-expert/xcxin.filexpert) supports this. If you long press on any file it gives you an "Open with" option, and then you can (as far as I know) pick from *any* application on your phone to open the file. Other file managers might do this, too, but I'm not sure. I'll add this to my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [touchqode](http://www.touchqode.com/) app to see a nice code editor including syntax highlighting, a special keyboard and code recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Android Web Developer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd). I am developer of this application.

[image]

With this app you can see the result in application or in external browser (e.g. Chrome)

**Other features:**

- Support all major web languages and formats: PHP, JavaScript, CSS, HTML
- A lot of ways to reach your project ( FTP, FTPS, SFTP, WEBDav and growing)
- Code highlighting
- Code completion
- Error checking
- Hardware keyboard support (e.g hotkeys)
- Code beautifying with one click
- Tablet ready UI
- Line numbering
- Quick preview of your page
- Highlighting the current line
- Search and replace with regular expressions
- Unlimited Undo/redo
- Full screen mode
- Recent projects
- Periodical autosaving
- Rename/create/delete/copy-paste files inside you project

Hope it helps.